# Symfony Twig: Defining the getGlobals() method in the "assetic" is deprecated

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I am using Symfony 2.3 (I still do not want to update it), and I received that warning and wanted to know how to solve it since I am new to this and I do not know how to solve it.

```
 DEPRECATED - Defining the getGlobals() method in the "assetic" extension is deprecated without explicitly implementing Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface.
```